# How can I echo PHP and HTML in the same line?

Tags: php

All I want to do is echo out a PHP variable inside a `<li>` tag. Refer to the code below. What's the proper format? Mine is not working.

```
$row['cat_title'];

echo "<li> {$cat_title} </li>";
```

Comment: Are you using a template engine (e.g. smarty) ?

Comment: Templating would be the way to go IMO, in addition to the `echo`-based answers, you could also use `(s)printf('<li>%s</li>', $row['cat_title']);`. Your use of `$row` does worry me: it's indicative of your mixing in markup (templating/view related code) with DB related code. That's considered bad practice

Comment: PHP **is** a templating engine. Including an entire 3rd party templating engine to accomplish simple string concatenation/interpolation is ridiculous. If this is in a template/view, use `<li><?= $cat_title ?></li>`, otherwise use `'<li>' . $cat_title . '</li>'`.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to output a value of a particular array key (e.g. `$row['cat_title']`) in HTML, you have quite a few options.

You can use the [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) (`.`):

```
echo '<li>' . $row['cat_title'] . '</li>';
```

You can use variable interpolation with [simple string parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple) (note that in this syntax, quotes around the array key must be omitted):

```
echo "<li>$row[cat_title]</li>";
```

You can use variable interpolation with [complex string parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) (using `{}`) which is actually not necessary here, but useful for more interpolating more complex expressions. With this syntax, quotes around the array key *should* be included.:

```
echo "<li>{$row['cat_title']}</li>";
```

You can output plain HTML and use the [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) shortcut syntax `<?=` to output the value (only do this if you are already outputting HTML, *not* if you are currently in a `<?php` tag; that would be a syntax error.):

```
<li><?= $row['cat_title'] ?></li>
```

You can use [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) (thanks to Elias Van Ootegem's comment for reminding me of this; I should have included it to begin with). `sprintf` can be used if you want to save the result to a variable instead; `printf` will output it immediately:

```
printf('<li>%s</li>', $row['cat_title']);
```

The first argument of `printf` is a format string, where `%s` is a string [conversion specification](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#refsect1-function.sprintf-parameters) that will take the value of `$row['cat_title']` when `printf` is executed.

There are other ways, but these are the most common.

Comment: You forgot the best option: `<li><?= $row['cat_title'] ?></li>`. There is **no reason** to use `<? php echo ...` when `<?=` is available everywhere and completely safe to use.

Comment: @meagar You're right. Writing answers so as to avoid "this didn't work on my PHP 5.2 server" responses is a lazy habit I need to break. I suppose the appropriate answer to those types of replies is not "then you'll have to use `<?php echo` instead," it's really "you need to stop using outdated PHP versions." I shouldn't be reducing the quality of my answers to support people's bad habits.

Comment: This is a really good and comprehensive answer. I flagged the question as a duplicate of another question but I feel like this is a better answer than the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. It seems like it definitely could be considered a duplicate. I'm not sure if this question specifically asking about outputting an array key rather than a simple variable makes it distinct from that one or not. FWIW, my answer does address some specifics of that that would be irrelevant to the other question.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<li>'.$var.'</li>';
```

OR

```
echo "<li>$var</li>";
```

OR

```
<li><?=$var?></li>
```

Comment: @DuaneLortie Please stop spreading misinformation. That tag will work in *all* modern versions of PHP since PHP 5.4, regardless of whether short tags are on or off. `<?=` has nothing to do with short tags, it's safe to use, and has been for a long, long time.

Comment: @Robert For all modern versions of php, `<?=` is fine. See above, and stop spreading this misinformation.

Comment: This is dependent on the clients php version.

Comment: @Robert No, that is exactly the misinformation I'm asking you to stop spreading. Assuming the client is running a version of PHP made in the last 4.5 years, it is safe to use. Even before PHP 5.4, it was **still** safe to use. You can't avoid all the parts of PHP that *some* servers might not be configured for, or you have to avoid 90% of PHP. The sane thing to do is pick a host that supports the parts of the language you're using, not avoid all parts that might not be available on every single PHP installation everywhere.

Comment: You're right in this manner. The client should be picking the correct host, but me personally always asume the client knows nothing about hosting ect.

Comment: @Robert Again, the host *doesn't matter*, because every host worth using is running **at least** PHP 5.4, where `<?=` is *guaranteed* to be available.

Comment: My bad folks.. "Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled. "     so yes, 
<li><?= $row['cat_title'] ?></li>    should work fine

Comment: Again I personally assume all of my clients are dumb so I would not use short tags ect.

Comment: It blows my mind that there are still PHP devs who think `<?=` is a short tag. They are not the same thing, and people should really stop advocating against the use of `<?=` which the language authors have explicitly guaranteed to be available for our use. It has been almost 5 years since "avoid `<?=`" was sound advice, if it ever was. Every version of PHP where `<?=` support is optional has been officially retired and unsupported for *years*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the right variable. You're on the right track, though.

```
echo "<li> {$row['cat_title']} </li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is mostly PHP in the file then:

```
<?php echo "<li>" . $row['cat_title'] . "</li>"; ?>
```

Or conversely if it's mostly HTML in the file then:

```
<li><?php echo $row['cat_title']; ?></li>
```

It sounds to me that it's most likely the second option you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative:

```
<li><?php echo $row['cat_title']; ?></li>
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted it: Please tell me why in the world is it wrong

Answer (score -1):

Either of these methods will work...

```
// Use single quotes and periods like this...
echo '<li>'. $row['cat_title'] .'</li>';
```

OR

```
 // Use double quotes like this...
 echo "<li> $row['cat_title'] </li>";
```

Comment: Method 1 works, but method 2 contains a syntax error.